# How do you rename files specifically in a list that wget will use?

Tags: wget

I have a file with a list of links to some youtube videos.

When I run the command:

```
wget -i list
```

Everything works just fine, however wget is automatically renaming the files to the gibberish at the end of each link. Running wget manually is not an option because there are far too many links. How do I go about giving a custom name to the links that wget will recognize?

Comment: Can you include an example URL and an example of what it is that `wget` does to it and what filename you would prefer for `wget` to use in that case?

Comment: What are you asking? can you make it more clear?

Answer (score 10):

The `-O` option allows you to specify the destination file name. But if you're downloading multiple files at once, `wget` will save all of their content to the file you specify via `-O`. Note that **in either case, the file will be truncated** if it already exists. See [the man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) for more info.

You can exploit this option by telling `wget` to download the links one-by-one:

```
while IFS= read -r url;do
    fileName="blah" # Add a rule to define a new name for each file here
    wget -O "$fileName" "$url"
done < list
```

You can also take [JJoao's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196253/how-do-you-rename-files-specifically-in-a-list-that-wget-will-use/196267#comment329176_196267) and add a file name next to each URL in the file then do:

```
while IFS= read -r url fileName;do
    wget -O "$fileName" "$url"
done < list
```

where it is assumed you have added a (unique) file name after each URL in the file (separated by a space).

Comment: @JJoao Thanks. Good suggestion; I'll add it to the amswer.

Comment: It is possible though that a single connection would be able to optimize downloading multiple files at once more efficiently. Readers may also be interested in `parallel`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751219/895245

Answer (score 4):

Make it simple, do not complicate ur life...

make a bash script call it list.sh and add the lines

```
wget url -O your-filename 
wget url2 -O your-filename2
```

as many as you want, and make it executable

```
chmod 775 list.sh
```

the run it `./list.sh`

Comment: Even though the answer does not technically address the problem, it sheds some damn deep philosophical light on our way of thinking as human beings. +1.

Comment: If i want to get 50 files should i write it 50 times? This is why have scripts for. To make our life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `youtube-dl` manpage.

```
youtube-dl -a URL-file -o '-o "%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

(untested)